# Merge two tables

Tags: ssis

I have two excel source. Consider first has 5 (F1, F2, F3, F4, F5) columns and the second has two columns (F6, F7).

I need to transfer this to a single table in the database which has all these seven columns. Which transformation, I should use to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: How do you intend to match up the rows?

Answer (score 0):

Merge or Merge Join.

Merge if they are sorted to match.

Join, if you want to match based on a field.